# While selecting Recent files getting null value content provider

Tags: android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-7.0-nougat, android-file, android-fileprovider

Code is working fine when selecting file / image from Gallary, file manager, download folder. i m able to get file path from `URI` using content provider. but while selecting recent files in `naugat` Android API version `7.0` and above content provider return null. I already spend two days on this and Now i m about to shaking my mind to get this working. I searched on SO and did not find any question related to mine Hence i m posting my question.

Here is Intent picker

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
}
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activity.Add_TOPIC_REQUEST_STORAGE);
```

And here i m extracting data from intent Data

```js
if (data.getData() != null) {
  Uri uri = data.getData();
  Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:  => checkingIntentCodeAndShowImage => INTETNT_OPEN_FOR_GALLERY_RIGHT_IMAGE is called - getting imageurl from intent data" + uri);

  String mimeType = activity.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
      if (mimeType == null) {
          String path = getPath(activity, uri);
          cMethods.cmShowLog(TAG,"checkingIntentCodeAndShowImage => path => " +path);

          if (path == null) {
              cMethods.cmShowLog(TAG,"checkingIntentCodeAndShowImage => path => " +path);
              cMethods.cmShowToast(strings.unexpected_error_occured, getActivityContext);
              cMethods.cmShowToast("file path is null ", getActivityContext);

              //filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uri.toString());
          } else {
              picturePath = path;
              File file = new File(path);
              cMethods.cmShowLog(TAG,"checkingIntentCodeAndShowImage => file => " +picturePath);
              //filename = file.getName();
              updatingCamerImageList(cMethods, picturePath, activity, openedFor, filesFiledsListValue, productOptionValueIdAndOptionId, pojo);

          }
      } else {
          String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
          Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePath, null, null, null);
          c.moveToFirst();
          int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
          picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
          c.close();
          cMethods.cmShowLog(TAG,"checkingIntentCodeAndShowImage => picturePath => " +picturePath);
          if(picturePath!=null) {
              updatingCamerImageList(cMethods, picturePath, activity, openedFor, filesFiledsListValue, productOptionValueIdAndOptionId, pojo);
          } else {
              cMethods.cmShowToast(strings.unexpected_error_occured, getActivityContext);
              cMethods.cmShowToast("content provider return value", getActivityContext);
          }


      }
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:  addPostImagesList code 12  - intent data is null");
  cMethods.cmShowToast(strings.unexpected_error_occured, getActivityContext);
  cMethods.cmShowToast("uri is null", getActivityContext);
}
```

I m only getting null value of path from URI when selecting recent files in `Naugat`.